# Why is ImageButton (Android - Java) not implementing onClick on actual image

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, imagebutton

I have not found a clear answer on this so I figured I would write a post to see if anybody can point me in the right direction.

Basically I am creating a Voice Notes application and I have set a 'delete' button for the locally saved files as a trash can image for an ImageButton. Seeing as users will be able to save as many audio files as they want I implemented a loop where the button is created, the ID is set via setID, and then a click listener is used based on the generated ID.

My problem is that the click listener works on the sides of the image, but not on the actual image, meaning if I click to the right or left of the ImageButton the file is deleted, however, when I actually click the trash can image in the ImageButton, nothing happens. I also have logs being registered anytime the button is clicked and they also don't work when I click the actual image, so I am sure the issue is that somehow the listener is not being used when the ImageButton is clicked. - Please remember that I said the click registers to the right and left of the image.

Here is the relevant code:

```
            try{
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    //Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView fileButton = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    fileButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    fileButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_button_colors);
                    fileButton.setTypeface(fileButton.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    fileButton.setText((i+1)+")   "+listOfFiles[i].getName());
                    fileButton.setId(i);
                    fileButton.setPadding(10,10,10,10);//LTRB
                    fileButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);


                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    RelativeLayout deleteButton = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_buttons, null);
                    deleteButton.setId(i+i);

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(deleteButton.getId()) );//WORKS AS EXPECTED
                    deleteButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                    TableRow horizontalButtonTableRow= new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                            (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    int leftMargin=0;int topMargin=15;int rightMargin=0;int bottomMargin=0;
                    tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

                    horizontalButtonTableRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

                    horizontalButtonTableRow.addView(fileButton);
                    horizontalButtonTableRow.addView(deleteButton);


                    final String fileName = saveDirectory.toString() + File.separator +
                            listOfFiles[i].getName();

                    fileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "should be playing audio");
                            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                            try {
                                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                                vib.vibrate(25);

                                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, fileName);
                                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(e));
                            }
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });

                    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {


                            try {
                                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                                vib.vibrate(25);

                                File deleteFile = new File(fileName);
                                deleteFile.delete();
                                savedFileLoader();
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, fileName+": WAS DELETED");

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(e));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    verticalButtonContainerLayout.addView(horizontalButtonTableRow);
                }//END IF
            }//END FOR
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,e.toString());
        }
```

MORE INFO(but not used in final solution): If I change my code for the inflater to work like this the imageButton is no longer added to my view. I think this happens because I am forced to remove the image button from the original relative view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = 
(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                RelativeLayout deleteButtonLayout = (RelativeLayout) 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_buttons, null);
                ImageButton deleteButton =  
deleteButtonLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                deleteButtonLayout.removeView(deleteButton);
                deleteButton.setId(i+i);
```

If I opt not to use removeView I get this exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Here is XML for imageButton in relative layout:

UPDATE: I have corrected my code based on the approved answer provided by @John Tribe. The "fix" was to set the RelativeLayout to clickable and at the same time setting the ImageButton to not be clickable. Doing this allowed my entire inflated layout to be clickable, which is exactly what I needed for this problem seeing as there was only 1 element in my inflated RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton

        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="false"

        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@drawable/trash"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are not using an ImageButton you are using a RelativeLayout. `RelativeLayout deleteButton = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_buttons, null);
                    deleteButton.setId(i+i);` try using an ImageButton instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used RelativeLayout , You should use Image or ImageButton,but if you really want to use RelativeLayout , then in xml  add `android:clickable="true"`.

Another approach can be by finding ImageButton and setting listener.

```
ImageButton deleteButton = deleteButtonLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
deleteButton.setOnClickListener( new On...);
```

Comment: Please check most recent edit @John Tribe. I already have this implemented in my XML and it does not seem to work. I originally thought that I could just make the entire inflated relative layout use an onClickListener but that does not seem to be working

Comment: I just realized that I set the clickable attribute to my ImageButton not the RelativeView... I will test when I get back home and let you know if it works.

Comment: I was about to write this :D

Comment: Yes, setting the RelativeLayout to clickable was the solution, for anybody that runs across this thread ensure you also set the ImageButton clickable attribute to false. Thank you very much @John Tribe!